# How to query records that don't follow expected pattern with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that may look like this:

```
ID | ACTION
1  | 'start'
2  | 'stop'
3  | 'start'
4  | 'stop'
5  | 'start'
...| ...
```

my question is, how can I detect with an SQL query if the start/stop pattern breaks, such as two stops without a start in between and vice versa?

I want a query to show all records that break the pattern. You could say that when there are two start/stop actions, you cannot be sure which of the two records are to blame, so I would like to have both records added to the query.

I know how to do this with VBA, but I do not see a way to use VBA with a query.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want any row where the next row is the same type or the previous row is the same type.

Assuming the ids have no gaps, you can get the information you need using joins:

```
select t.*
from (t as t left join
      t as tnext
      on tnext.id = t.id + 1
     ) left join
     t as tprev
     on tprev.id = t.id - 1
where t.action in (tprev.action, tnext.action);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no gaps in your ids:

```
select * from tablename as t
where 
  action in (select action from tablename where id in (t.id - 1, t.id + 1))
```